# get values from object and push into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to get values from object and save it into array...This is how my object is structured.

```
0: {name: "John Deo", age: 45, gender: "male"}
1: {name: "Mary Jeo", age: 54, gender: "female"}
2: {name: "Saly Meo", age: 55, gender: "female"}
```

But I am looking for something like this.

```
0: ["John Deo", 45, "male"]
1: ["Mary Jeo", 54, "female"]
2: ["Saly Meo", 55, "female"]
```

This is where I got stuck.

```
for(let i in data){
   _.map(data[i], value =>{
        console.log(value)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your data and run the function [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on each object to extract its values as an array.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "John Deo", age: 45, gender: "male"},
  {name: "Mary Jeo", age: 54, gender: "female"},
  {name: "Saly Meo", age: 55, gender: "female"}
];
result = data.map(Object.values);
    
console.log(result);
```

Note that iterating over properties of an object this way might return then in an [arbitrary order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties) so if you need to ensure the order you should use a custom function to extract the values (this is especially easy using ES6 destructuring):

```js
const data = [
  {name: "John Deo", age: 45, gender: "male"},
  {name: "Mary Jeo", age: 54, gender: "female"},
  {name: "Saly Meo", age: 55, gender: "female"}
];
const extractValues = ({name, age, gender}) => [name, age, gender];
result = data.map(extractValues);
        
console.log(result);
```

Comment: THANKS! you don't know how long that took me. it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.map(obj => Object.values(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the Object.values() method.

```
var obj = {name: "John Deo", age: 45, gender: "male"}; 

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```